# How do I post a snippet to slack channel

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am trying to post log info to slack and some of these logs can get pretty big.  Is there a way to send it as a snippet so that slack doesn't chunk the text into multiple messages?

Comment: A quick look through the docs turns up that you upload it as a "file": https://api.slack.com/types/file https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload Is there anything specific about that you're looking to ask?

Comment: Well, I am wanting to post log files to a slack channel in markdown (or some other nice on the eyes) format.  The logs can get big sometimes and slack chunks the messages ruining the markdown that I had in there so I was wondering if it was possible to post that log description as a snippet instead so that it was easy to read in the slack channel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can post a snippet to a Slack channel using the API method [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload).

In order for this to work you need to:

- Use the `content` (not the `file`) parameter to upload the content of
  your file.
- Provide the name of the channel in the `channels` parameter where the
  snippet should be posted.
- The `filetype` is optional. Slack will determine the type of your
  file based on the filename or "magic bytes" of the file. e.g. using
  `text` as `filetype` will work.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with botkit ?

Comment: Note: to get this working, I've also had to create a second message containing a link to the uploaded file. It seems that using files.upload alone only uploads a file but does not post a message in a channel linking to that file.

Comment: Are you sure you included `channels` in your request? that is required to get the file posted in a channel. You can also add a message with `initial_comment`.